# How do I remove error in installing ignite-cli?

Tags: react-native

I am a beginner in react native in ignite. By mistake I installed ignite-cli twice with this command: 
    npm install -g ignite-cli

Now it shows this error:

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\boidurja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ignite-cli\bin\ignite
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\boidurja\AppData\Roaming\npm\ignite
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 
'C:\Users\boidurja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ignite-cli\bin\ignite' -> 
'C:\Users\boidurja\AppData\Roaming\npm\ignite'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\boidurja\AppData\Roaming\npm\ignite
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\boidurja\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-21T04_32_24_707Z-debug.log
```

I can't create a new project. When I create a new project(ignite new myproject) it shows this error:

```
C:\Users\boidurja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ignite\node_modules\root-path\index.js:20
throw new Error('cannot find any package.json file');
^

Error: cannot find any package.json file
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\boidurja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ignite\node_modules\root- 
path\index.js:20:9)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
at Module._compile 
(C:\Users\boidurja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ignite\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
at Object.newLoader [as .js] 
(C:\Users\boidurja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ignite\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(C:\Users\boidurja\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ignite\dist\ignite.js:36:40)
```

How do I remove these errors so that I will be able to create a new project?

Comment: Have you tried npm install first?

Comment: I can't create a new project. Where do I do ```npm install```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check if you have installed the latest version of node.

```
node -v
```

Then install **Yarn**  (https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install)
After that , type following commands

```
yarn global add ignite-cli
ignite new MyNewAppName
```

Comment: Do you know how to run a react-native project in an android device connected to a laptop at an USB port?